# Asymptotics for 2 Humbert series special forms

Tags: asymptotics, improper-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I have 2 Humbert seriers special forms that arise in a quantum physics problem. $a$ and $x$ are real.
$$\phi_1(1+ia,ia,ia+3/2;1/2,ix)$$
$$\phi_2(ia,-ia,1/2;ix,-ix)$$
I want to find asymptotic expansions when $x \to \infty$ in order to compute precise approximations when x is sufficiently large.
N.B. $\phi_1$ can be written as an Euler type integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series
$$\phi_1(1+ia,ia,ia+3/2;1/2,ix)=\frac{\Gamma(3/2+ia)}{\Gamma(1+ia)\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{ia}(1-t/2)^{-ia}}{\sqrt{1-t}} e^{ixt} dt$$

Comment: For the integral representation of $\Phi_1$, the steepest descent direction at the endpoints is $i$. Taking the contour to be $[0, i \epsilon, 1 + i \epsilon, 1]$ gives
$$\Phi_1 = -\frac
  {e^{3 \pi i/4} 2^{i a} \Gamma(3/2 + i a) e^{i x}}
  {\Gamma(1 + i a) \sqrt x} +
 O(x^{-1}).$$
An integral representation for $\Phi_2$ is obtained from
$$\mathcal L[(\pi x)^{-1/2} \Phi_2] =
p^{-1/2} (p - i)^{-i a} (p + i)^{i a}.$$
Take the contour that goes along the upper and lower banks of the branch cuts (which is the steepest descent for $e^{x p}$). Then
$$\Phi_2 = e^{-\pi a} + O(x^{-1/2}).$$

Comment: Beautiful! Can this technique be continued somehow to obtain higher order terms?

Comment: Certainly. We have two integrals of the form $\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + i \infty} f(t) e^{i x t} dt$ for $\Phi_1$ and three integrals of the form $\int_{i y_0}^{-\infty + i y_0} f(p) e^{x p} dp$ for $\Phi_2$. Expanding $f$ into series around the finite endpoint ($x_0$ or $i y_0$) and integrating gives as many terms in the asymptotic expansion as we want.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but is all this "the method of steepest descent"? Can you suggest a reference so I can understand this better?

Comment: Correct, it's the steepest descent method, the last step is applying Watson's lemma. I'd suggest Bender, Orszag, *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers*.

Comment: I'm having trouble comming up with the right series expansion to come up with more terms.

Comment: You need to get the integrals into the desired form first. Have you written $\Phi_1$ as a sum of integrals over vertical rays $[x_0, x_0 + i \infty)$ and $\Phi_2$ as a sum of integrals over horizontal rays $[i y_0, -\infty + i y_0)$?

Comment: let's look at the integral $I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{ia} (1-t/2)^{-ia}}{(1-t)^{1/2}} e^{ixt} dt$ Deforming the contour like you suggested, noticing that the middle segment vanishes and introducing a change of variables yields $I = 
\frac{i}{x^{1+ia}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(ip)^{ia}(1-\frac{ip}{2x})^{-ia}}{(1-ip/x)^{1/2}} e^{-p} dp 
-\frac{i e^{ix} 2^{ia}}{x^{1/2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+\frac{ip}{x})^{ia}(1-\frac{ip}{x})^{-ia}}{(-ip)^{1/2}} e^{-p}$

Comment: Correct, but we need an integrand of the form $f(u) e^{-x u}$. Take $p = x u$. Then expand $f(u)$ into series around zero (the leading order is $u^{i a}$ for the first integrand and $u^{-1/2}$ for the second integrand) and integrate termwise.

Comment: See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239534/asymptotic-expansion-of-an-euler-type-integral) for the answer done with Mathematica.